# Let $f(z) = \frac{z^{-2}}{\sin( \pi z )}$. What is the residue for $z \neq 0$?

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

Let $f(z) = \frac{z^{-2}}{\sin( \pi z )}$. What is the residue for $z \neq 0$?

In a pdf online, it states we may calculate the residue using the "derivative trick" to get:
$$
\mathrm{Res}(f,n) = \frac{n^{-2}}{\pi \cos(\pi n)} = \frac{(-1)^n}{\pi n^2}.
$$
What is the "derivative trick" that is being referred to? I know from the definition of a simple pole that 
$$
\mathrm{Res}(f,n) = \lim_{z \to n} (z-n) f(z).
$$
So I suppose this could be the "derivative trick" since
$$
\lim_{z \to n} \frac{\sin(\pi z)}{(z-n)} = \frac{d}{dz} \sin(\pi n) = \pi \cos(\pi z).
$$
But this is just the definition of a simple pole. Or is there another "derivative trick" for calculating residues that I'm not aware of? Perhaps I'm reading into the text too much. It can be found [here](http://people.duke.edu/~ad159/files/m185/23.pdf) at the end of page 4.

Comment: You understood the text correctly and the "derivative trick" is what you have explained. It will not work though for the residue at $z=0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In situations like this I prefer to use the definition of the residue, which is simply the coefficient of $(z-z_n)^{-1}$ in the Laurent expansion about a pole at $z=z_n$.  In this case, the poles are at integers $z=n$, so we expand about $\zeta=z-n$:

$$f(z) = \frac{(n+\zeta)^{-2}}{\sin{\pi(n+\zeta)}} = \frac{(-1)^n}{n^2 \sin{\pi \zeta} } \left (1+\frac{\zeta}{n} \right )^{-2}$$

Near a pole $z=n$, i.e., for small $\zeta$, the coefficient of $\zeta^{-1}$ is $(-1)^n/(\pi n^2)$.  This is the residue of $f$ about the pole $z=n$.

Comment: Could you expand on how you know the value of the coefficient in your second to last sentence from the right side of the equality? I don't know how to perform a Laurent expansion on your result.

Comment: @mathjacks: $\sin{\pi \zeta} = \pi \zeta [1+O(\zeta^2)]$ so that $$\frac1{\sin{\pi \zeta}} = \frac1{\pi \zeta} + O(\zeta)$$

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. Understood